# Android: How to have a common socket connection to server in all activities

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am pretty new to android. How could I make a socket connection to a server which is available to all the activities, instead of me establishing connection to the same server in every activity?

In the MainActivity I have a thread which is running, but this is thread is not accesible by other activities.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    private Socket socket;
    private static final int SERVERPORT = 8020;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.36";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         new Thread(new ServerThread()).start();
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    private Socket socket;
    private static final int SERVERPORT = 8020;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.36";

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }
```

How do i make the same connection to server on 192.168.1.36 available to all activities instead of me creating a connection on every activity.

**EDIT TO ANSWER**

I created a class which stores all the connection parameters
     package com.example.clientmobile2;

```
 public class DataHolderClass {
 private static DataHolderClass dataObject = null;

 private DataHolderClass() {
 // left blank intentionally
 }

public static DataHolderClass getInstance() {
if (dataObject == null)
    dataObject = new DataHolderClass();
return dataObject;
}
private int server_port=8020;
private String server_ip="192.168.1.33";;

public int get_server_port() {
return server_port;
}


public String get_server_ip() {
return server_ip;
}

}
```

MainActivity is as follows :-

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    private static final int SERVERPORT = DataHolderClass.getInstance().get_server_port();
private static final String SERVER_IP = DataHolderClass.getInstance().get_server_ip();
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
     }
     public void onClickon(View view) {
    Socket socket = null;
    try{

        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

        socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

    //sending the message to the linino as 0 to turn of the light
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
            true);
    out.println("0"); 
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
   }
```

The application crashes everytime i click on the button associated with onClickOn.

Error Log

```
05-08 10:38:40.171: E/AndroidRuntime(12909): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 10:38:40.171: E/AndroidRuntime(12909): Process: com.example.clientmobile2, PID: 12909
05-08 10:38:40.171: E/AndroidRuntime(12909): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-08 10:38:40.171: E/AndroidRuntime(12909):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3841)
05-08 10:38:40.171: E/AndroidRuntime(12909):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
05-08 10:38:40.171: E/AndroidRuntime(12909):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18462)
05-08 10:38:40.171: E/AndroidRuntime(12909):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-08 10:38:40.171: E/AndroidRuntime(12909):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-08 10:38:40.171: E/AndroidRuntime(12909):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-08 10:38:40.171: E/AndroidRuntime(12909):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
05-08 10:38:40.171: E/AndroidRuntime(12909):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 10:38:40.171: E/AndroidRuntime(12909):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-08 10:38:40.171: E/AndroidRuntime(12909):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
05-08 10:38:40.171: E/AndroidRuntime(12909):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
05-08 10:38:40.171: E/AndroidRuntime(12909):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-08 10:38:40.171: E/AndroidRuntime(12909): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-08 10:38:40.171: E/AndroidRuntime(12909):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 10:38:40.171: E/AndroidRuntime(12909):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-08 10:38:40.171: E/AndroidRuntime(12909):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3836)
05-08 10:38:40.171: E/AndroidRuntime(12909):    ... 11 more
05-08 10:38:40.171: E/AndroidRuntime(12909): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 10:38:40.171: E/AndroidRuntime(12909):    at com.example.clientmobile2.MainActivity.onClickon(MainActivity.java:331)
```

Comment: use `SINGLTON PATTERN` for creating a `Socket` connection...

Answer (score 0):

you can create a `singleton class` and define that object there or either use `application` class which is provided by android and then define your socket object there.Then your object will accessible in all activities.  [read here](http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/) how to use Application class.

Comment: thanks for the reply! Was reading about the singleton class. Just have a query there. Instead of creating a thread, can i just establish a connection to the server, everytime a method in the singleton class is called and close the connection at the end of the function?

Comment: no..in application on create method create a connection to the server and then create a method their which return the connected connection object.no need to connect again to server

Answer (score 0):

here in this case you have to use SINGLETON CLASS.from your first screen you have to set the creditiontials then you have yo get them at any screen.you can use the  below code:

```
public class DataHolderClass {
private static DataHolderClass dataObject = null;

private DataHolderClass() {
    // left blank intentionally
}

public static DataHolderClass getInstance() {
    if (dataObject == null)
        dataObject = new DataHolderClass();
    return dataObject;
}
    private int server_port;
private String server_ip;

    public String get_server_port() {
    return server_port;
}

public void set_server_port(String server_port) {
    this._server_port = server_port;
}

    public String get_server_ip() {
    return server_ip;
}

public void set_server_ip(String server_ip) {
    this.server_ip= server_ip;
}

}
```

now in your activity you have to set the values like below:

```
DataHolderClass.getInstance().set_server_port("8020");
DataHolderClass.getInstance().set_server_ip("192.168.1.36");
```

now to get the values use below code:

```
 String a = DataHolderClass.getInstance().get_server_port();
String b = DataHolderClass.getInstance().get_server_ip();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. ! So does it mean that everytime i enter an activity, i use the String a = DataHolderClass.getInstance().get_server_port(); to get the port address and String b = DataHolderClass.getInstance().get_server_ip();to get the server IP? Also does this mean that I do not need to use threads?

Comment: yes everytime you just have to get connection variables.

Comment: @user3460885.. not too fast... what is your perpose for creating a Socket?? If you are going to make blocking calls then you ll have to use background thread..

Comment: Hey @DevCarlsberg check out the edit to the question. The application seems to be crashing everytime the button is clicked where the connection is established.

Comment: @Rupesh I am creating a socket to send a message to the server and nothing else.

Comment: @user3460885 have you added the permission `android.permission.INTERNET` to the `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: You have to add this line:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
 
outside the application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: it's `NullPointerException`.. may I know which is this line 331.. at  com.example.clientmobile2.MainActivity.onClickon(MainActivity.java:331)

Comment: paste line number 331 here